# Dynamic drop down Jsp

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

I want to have a drop down list that changes when i change the first drop down.
I'm sure my servlet is right, because it returns the values i need, but my servlet don't run. When i debug it doesn't hit the breakpoint in the servlet.

I think it's something with my javascript.

here is the JSP file:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="dropDownOnderdelen.js"></script>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
 Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action="/Racing/UploadServlet" method="post"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="file"  />
<br />
Logische Naam: <input type="text" name="logicalName"><br>
Stuknr(automatisch,nog niet geimplementeerd): <input type="text" name="partNr"><br>
Kost: <input type="text" name="cost"><br>


Assembly:
<select name = "assembly">
 <c:forEach var ="assembly" items="${Assemblys}">
 <option value="${assembly.id}">${assembly.name}</option>
 </c:forEach>
 </select>
 <select id="onderdeel">
 <option>Kies eerst een assembly</option>
 </select>
 <br>
  <textarea name="comments" cols="25" rows="5">
  Verdediging Design
  </textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And this is the javascript file

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#assembly').change(function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var servletUrl = 'OnderdelenServlet?value=' + selectedValue;

    $.getJSON(servletUrl, function(options) {
        var dropdown2 = $('#onderdeel');
        $('>option', dropdown2).remove(); // Clean old options first.
        if (options) {
            $.each(opts, function(key, value) {
                dropdown2.append($('<option/>').val(key).text(value));
            });
        } else {
            dropdown2.append($('<option/>').text("Please select dropdown1"));
        }
    });
  });
});
```

The servlet is ok, i'm sure of that, so no need to put it here.

Answer (score 2):

You have used

$('#assembly').change  ===> # stands for ID (element ID)

in your javascript

where as in your JSP file you have < select> as 
< select name = "assembly">

so assign "ID" as well to you < select> box
< select name = "assembly" id="assembly">

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed a fault, but it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Here what i am doing in the same case

discipline is my first combo id ;

```
$("#discipline").change(function() {
         var data = $("#discipline option:selected").text();

                $.ajax({
                      type: 'POST',
                      url: 'registerdcodes?type=discipline&discipline='+data,
                      success:function(data){  
                    fillComboBox(data,$("#codes"));//populating secondcombo
                      }
                    });

     });
```

Added fillcombomethod also :

If you need "please select your options"  as afirst item  pass `isSelectRequired`  `true`

And the villlagesString is a bigString sperated by |

// Ex:villagesString  should like this ..
villagesString ="option1|option2|option3|option4";

```
    function fillComboBox(villagesStrings,box,isSelctRequired){
        if(villagesStrings !=null){
            var villagesStrings = villagesStrings.split('|');
            if(isSelctRequired){
            box.append("<option value='null'>Please select your option</option>");
            }
            for (var i = 0, l = villagesStrings.length-1; i <l; i++){
                var id =villagesStrings[i].substring(0,2);
                var qtn =villagesStrings[i].substring(0,villagesStrings[i].length)
                box.append("<option value="+qtn+">"+qtn+"</option>");
        }
        }

        }
```

Comment: if you need i'l provide fillComboBox(data,$("#codes")) implementation..good luck